# How to search progressive web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am interested in Progressive Web App and it has several advantages as mentioned at the below site

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-progressive-web-app/

One of them is that Progressive Web App is Discoverable.
Actually I don't understand it 100%.

It means we can search progressive web app  by googling.

I have three questions like below.

- How we can search Progressive Web App  by googling. Is there any keyword?
  Because progressive web app does not belong to any app store. Seems like it should be searched by googling and needs any group or category for all them.
- Which item of W3C manifests help it identifiable as “applications”
- How service worker registration scope allows search engines to find them

> Discoverable - Are identifiable as “applications” thanks to W3C manifests and service worker registration scope allowing search engines to find them.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the search engine.

Google can load pages and run the javascript inside them, this means it can index content that you render on your pages as long as all the URL's are discoverable.

There are a couple of things to watch out for though, not all search engines render JS, so you need to make sure you have a solid server render story for your content.  Not every search engine supports API's like promises (for example) so you will need to make sure that your app has the correct polyfills in place to function correctly.

I don't know of any search engine that uses or understands the manifest right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried of users not finding your PWA in Google or in any other search engine, you also have to consider the marketing side of this.  Its just like any other website or campaign that you launch.  You dont just launch your site/campaign and keep your fingers crossed that the users will find it by Googling it.  You have to gain traction from social media and blogs to let your users know that you have this wonder PWA in the internet.  From there, I am sure your PWA will gain enough traffic to be seen in the search results